# Push notification "Error Registration failed - permission denied" before prompt is clicked?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I'm trying to learn how to use `Push Notifications` but I am getting a

```
Registration failed - permission denied
```

Error even before I click allow or block the permission prompt.

The line that produces this error in my service worker file is

```
const subscription = await self.registration.pushManager.subscribe(options)
```

The strange thing is if I click allow notifications after the error and refresh the page it all works fine.

And when I check `window.Notification.requestPermission` it returns `granted`

Most of the code is from https://blog.atulr.com/web-notifications/

```
const urlB64ToUint8Array = base64String => {
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - (base64String.length % 4)) % 4)
  const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')
  const rawData = atob(base64)
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length)
  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i)
  }
  return outputArray
}

const saveSubscription = async subscription => {
  const SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:8081/save-subscription'
  const response = await fetch(SERVER_URL, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(subscription),
  })
  return response.json()
}

self.addEventListener('activate', async () => {
  // This will be called only once when the service worker is installed for first time.
  try {
    const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(
      'BO29MqroVuQiUch951aG0kASkvQy9S4OLshzA3xc12Ar3oAT7UMxjlsq3OMlQXQaSsZILLy7nWuvmbZNZ1YOrXo'
    )
    const options = { applicationServerKey, userVisibleOnly: true }
    const subscription = await self.registration.pushManager.subscribe(options)
    const response = await saveSubscription(subscription)
    console.log(response)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err.message)
  }
})

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  if (event.data) {
    console.log('Push event!! ', event.data.text())
    showLocalNotification('Yolo', event.data.text(), self.registration)
  } else {
    console.log('Push event but no data')
  }
})

const showLocalNotification = (title, body, swRegistration) => {
  const options = {
    body,
    // here you can add more properties like icon, image, vibrate, etc.
  }
  swRegistration.showNotification(title, options)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to request notification permission before you register service worker or subscribe to the push service.

According to the code in https://blog.atulr.com/web-notifications/, change the order of below two statements in index.js from

```
const swRegistration = await registerServiceWorker();
const permission =  await requestNotificationPermission();
```

to

```
const permission =  await requestNotificationPermission();    
const swRegistration = await registerServiceWorker();
```

This should fix the error message below.

> Registration failed - permission denied